# Sending a MAPI email via Java ( or C# )

Tags: c#, java, email, mapi

I have a java program that sends some emails currently using SMTP. I have a customer whose corporate network is locked down and only allows sending of emails via the MAPI1 and MAPI4 protocols.

After looking around on the internet I have been unable to find any examples of sending an MAPI email from a Java program. If we have to pay for some 3rd party component its not the end of the world, but free is obviously better :)

Another point to add is that if the task is much easier in C# then there is the possibility of creating the send email functionality in C# and calling the C# program from the Java main application.

Please let me know if you require anymore information.

Comment: Are you running the Java on a Windows box, i.e. can you use MAPI COM components? To be honest I'd just beg their ops team for an exception for your application - either way you'll need accounts and authentication to send from. (Although sending MAPI is an interesting question in itself anyway!)

Comment: Yes we are running on a windows box so could use MAPI COM components. Unfortunately there is no option of unlocking the network.

Answer (score 7):

All of the following can send mails via **MAPI** from Java:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/CMapiEx.aspx
- https://github.com/briandealwis/jmapi
- http://www.moyosoft.com/joc/ (commercial)
- http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/ (commercial) together with http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/ (COM bridge for Java)
- http://www.moonrug.com/features.html (commercial) (no longer appears to exist)

You will usually need the MAPI COM components on the local machine and always the credentials for the MAPI connection/Exchange account!

*Since I am not sure what you mean by MAPI4 versus MAPI1 I suspect that you might mean IMAP (there is a V 4 of the protocol) which is quite different from MAPI* - just in case the following are Java options for **IMAP**:

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/javamail143-243221.html
- http://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-imap.asp (commercial)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [JMapi](https://github.com/briandealwis/jmapi) library, it only works on windows machines but should do what you want ...

Comment: Do you know if this is the product found here? http://openmapi.org/jmapi It says its still in development on this link

Comment: yes is the same and is underdevelopment but from the link that i have posted you can clone the git repository and use it ...